# Нужна помощь по добавлению глубины резкости в движок Path tracing

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, glsl, pathtracing

Возможно вопрос глупый, но... Захотел я как-то со скуки сделать ray casting, а затем на нём path tracing используя фрагментный шейдер. Теперь я пробую добавить depth of field. Я пускаю луч по текущему пикселю, затем добавляю к его точке назначения случайное значение в зависимости от апертуры, а затем к перед выпусканием луча из камеры -> в сдвинутый пиксель меняю направление луча так, чтобы он добрался до заданной точки дальше от камеры или ближе к камере, в зависимости от focalDistance. Но из-за этого и fov картинки начинает зависеть от фокусного расстояния. Можно ли не изменяя fov это реализовать?

Вот и функции:

```
vec2 randomPointOnCircle(in float R) {
    float r = R * sqrt(random());
    float theta = random() * 2 * 3.14159265;
    return vec2(r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta));
}
vec3 depth_of_field(in vec2 fragPos, out vec2 randomizedPos) {
    randomizedPos = fragPos + randomPointOnCircle(u_cameraAperture / 100);
    vec3 rayDir = normalize(vec3(u_focalDist, randomizedPos));
    return rayDir;
}
```

Comment: *"затем добавляю к его точке назначения случайное значение"* - это еще зачем? По идее там надо прибавлять значение расстояния до фокальной плоскости, чтобы определить точку пересечения с ней, через которую потом надо будет пускать лучи с разбросом в зависимости от апертуры.

Comment: Всё же смог сделать, вернулся к тому варианту с которого в первый раз пробовал. Добавил разброс начала луча по кругу с заданным радиусом, потом этот луч сходится с его правильной точкой на заданном расстоянии от камеры. Но так как угол случайно изменён, он продолжает лететь криво. Таким образом этот луч только на некотором расстоянии от камеры пролетает ровно по своему пикселю.